# Android - Implement Views programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement an imageview and a textview side by side. I achieved this by using XML. However i wanted to achieve this programmatically but had no luck so far. My XML and Java code are below. Please help me to execute programmatically.

I'm executing the Java code in a fragment.

XML CODE:

```
<RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/rl1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image1"
        android:layout_width="160dip" 
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
        android:scaleType="fitXY" 
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/my_image1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/my_image1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/my_image1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA CODE:

```
RelativeLayout rl1 = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParams;
rlParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                 newLayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
rlParams.addRule(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
rl1.setLayoutParams(rlParams);

SmartImageView siv1 = new SmartImageView(getActivity());
siv1.setId(rand.nextInt(50000) + 1);
siv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width,height));
siv1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
siv1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
siv1.setImageUrl(Uri);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(getActivity());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams;
relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tv1.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
relativeLayoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
tv1.setText("Sample Text");

rl1.addView(siv1);
rl1.addView(tv1);
ll.addView(rl1);
```

By executing the above code, i'm getting the image but the text is inside the image. But, i want to get the image on the left and the text on the right.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the margin of your text like this

```
relativeLayoutParams.setMargins(200, 0, 0, 0);
```

but this is not the **best practice** so do one thing take linear layout set orientation to **horizontal** add both imageview and textview to it and then add this linearlayout to your relative layout.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @Lalith Mohan This is going to work too. It is a big difference if something worked and something worked your way. This is you avoiding the issue, question whether your way is proper is more of a design question, answers that are leading you to a different way sometimes can interfere with your concept. Next time if you want something just to work define that when you ask the question.

Comment: Thanks Marko. I appreciate your concern

Answer (score 5):

Add below code to your Activity:

```
rlParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, siv1);
rlParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, siv1);
rlParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, siv1);
tv1.setLayoutParams(rlParams);
```

and then do:

```
rl1.addView(siv1);
rl1.addView(tv1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a good answer, you are missing rules like in your XML, `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/my_image1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/my_image1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/my_image1"`, and Gagan told you how to set them.

Comment: You are welcome, I like straight questions and answers that goes accordingly, not just some workaround. Workaround is when you are desperate and need something just to work.

Answer (score 2):

In your case it is better to use a horizontal *LinearLayout*:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.setLayoutParams(param);

TextView textview = new TextView(getActivity());
...



SmartImageView siv1 = new SmartImageView(getActivity());
...

ll.addView(textview);
ll.addView(siv1);
```

Answer (score 2):

To align the views in RelativeLayout is much difficult. I will suggest you to use the TableRows or LinearLayouts. Both these give much easier way to align views side by side. Here is a source in which one TextView is aligned-left with 4 ImageViews aligned on its right. You can get idea from this
[TextView taking/consuming too much space above and below the text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16627237/2069130)